# Как сделать прилипающее меню книзу экрана с отступом?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Есть некий сайт site.ru, для которого создаются версия под ПК и версия под мобильные устройства.

Я чего то не могу сообразить как сделать прилипающее к низу экрана меню (как например в мобильной версии ВК) для мобильных устройств.

Меню сделал через:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 12;
```

Но вот дальше случается загадка: блок перекрывает контент, а посчитать его высоту чтобы сделать отступ фиксированной высоты невозможно - он всегда разный в зависимости от сценария использования.

Можно конечно посчитать длину через JS и JS-ом же делать такой `margin`, но предпочтительно решение без JS.

Comment: Зависит от Вашей верстки. Если у Вас отдельно контент, отдельно меню, то контенту присваиваете высоту calc(100vh - 60px), а меню высоту 60px (где 60px - высота меню, она может быть любой). В ином случае нужно смотреть, как Вы сверстали.

Comment: Способ написанный выше хорош. Можно ещё сделать `body {padding-bottom: 60px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы меню "прилипало" можно воспользоваться позицией [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu > span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div class="menu"><span>Menu<span/></div>
```

А с помощью JS сворачивать меню, когда, например, страница скроллится вниз.

Answer (score 0):

По какой причине высота меню зависит от сценария? Я вижу только два варианта:

1. Вы задаете для блока меню фиксированную высоту и тогда у тега Body можете задать фиксированный отступ снизу равный этой высоте
2. Если действительно высота должна быть разной в зависимости от сценария использования, то только с помощью js определять эту высоту и тем же js устанавливать соответствующий отступ (получится скрипт в пару строк буквально)